# Application based cms or package for laravel

Tags: laravel, web-applications, content-management-system, package, octobercms

I am writing a `Laravel` application. this application needs to a *CMS*.

my application have something like user membership,newsletter emails, authentication,advanced searches etc, depend on posts.
a `CMS` can not handle my application alone.
I need to an extendable `CMS` that resolves my requests.

I saw [October CMS gallery](https://octobercms.com/gallery) and I think it is for blog or simple sites not an extendable application.

What extendable `CMS` or package (in `Laravel`) can resolve my requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

October is pretty much amazing. I think you can do anything with it. When I saw their website the first time on a recommendation of a friend I also saw it as a simple CMS - but look at the documentation- and resources-page: You can create your own plugins, it has a very intricate and easy to understand databse-handling that also manages complicated relationships like "many to many polymorphic" and there is an easy way to create backend-pages that contain forms with those relations. In my opinion its really amazingly thought through and it can serve as CMS-part for almost anything.

Comment: Thank you @Johanness. is october fast or not (for an application)? and can i use all of the features of laravel in october? can i use laravel features in laravel way or october way? and for extend app in future should i scape october or i can extend with it? what time should i spend for october for full learning?

Comment: October is a developers CMS. It uses Laravel as base and of course you could install october and still work solely with laravel - but that would defeat the purpose: october facilitates the work with laravel and is still under heavy development - which means it hopefully will evolve greatly in the next few months. Still: The Beta phase is over and they are in production stage and it seems the code is very solid.

Comment: I don't know what your experience is - but if you watch the videos on octebercms.com/resources and read the documentation that should give you a good idea of how much you will have to invest to learn it. I am convinced that it is less than if you try to build a CMS on Laravel yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I think all you can do it with OctoberCMS, it is not pure CMS, it is developer first CMS, you can extends this as you want, there is no restriction in extending this, as per my opinion, all things you can do with laravel is possible with OctoberCMS.

Please double check its features https://octobercms.com/features

what you can do is you can keep Laravel and OctoberCMS in one project, for CMS part use OctoberCMS.

Comment: Thank you @Anand Patel. is october fast or not (for an application)? and can i use **all of the features** of laravel in october? can i use laravel features in laravel way or october way? and for extend app in future should i scape october or i can extend with it? what time should i spend for october for full learning?

Answer (score 1):

i heard talking about Platform by cartalyst but i never try it.
take look if you want and i think it responds to your needs.

https://cartalyst.com/manual/platform/4.0